# How can i delete items from FlatList one by one by clicking via state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-state

I've created a simple list into a FlatList, Items have been gotten from an array named `data`.  I want to remove items one by one by clicking on each item but my problem is that when i click on a item all of them get deleted simultaneously.

How can i fix this?

This is the  what look like my app:

[image]

**And this is the code:**

```
const FoodList = () => {




    const data = [

        { text: 'test1', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test2', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test3', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test4', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test5', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test6', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test7', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test8', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test9', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test10', backgroundColor: 'teal' },
        { text: 'test11', backgroundColor: 'teal' },


    ]




    let [itemState, setitemState] = useState(data);




    return (


        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={itemState}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={[
                            { flexDirection: 'row' }, { width: '100%' }, { alignItems: 'center' }, { flex: 1 }, { justifyContent: 'space-between' },
                            { backgroundColor: item.backgroundColor }, { marginBottom: 10 }

                        ]}
                        activeOpacity={0.7}
                        onPress={() => {
                            let removeItem = itemState.map((_item, _Index) => _Index !== index);
                            setitemState(itemState = removeItem);

                        }}

                    >


                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, color: 'white' }} >{item.text}{item.name}</Text>


                        <Icon type='FontAwesome5' name='trash-alt' style={{ color: 'white' }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}





            />



        </View>
    )

}
```

Comment: I think in this case you are going to need an actual item key, and not use the index alone. React reuses components with the same key, and when you delete an item from a list, that changes the index of every future item, which can cause bugs. That doesn't necessarily fix your observed issue, but it will prevent other bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead

```
onPress={() => {
   setitemState(prevItemState => prevItemState.filter((_item, _Index) => _Index !== index));
}}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it worked but i don't understand how does it work, Is there any reference?

Comment: First, you need filter instead of map, because map would create a new array of booleans for each element. Second, you can't pass the current state in a function and expect it to reflect changes (it will retain the value that it had when the component was drawn), so instead you can use setState(prevState => newState) instead of setState(newState). setState is immutable, so you don't need to worry about updating it inside the function. You can read more about that here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies on the function you used to remove item.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   function for every array element.
>
> The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements
>   that pass a test.

so when you run `map((_item, _Index) => _Index !== index)` your `removeItem` will be:

```
 [false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

bunch of booleans doesn't get rendered obviously :)

in order to to remove the item use `filter((_item, _Index) => _Index !== index)`

Comment: Thanks buddy, You clarified it very well.